# Why does my Listbox return the wrong Item

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sorting, data-binding, listbox

I populate a sorted ListBox (lbCustomer) via datasource which is a BindingList. The BindingList contains Items (customer) with a bunch of properties. DisplayMember is property "name" and ValueMember is property "id". Now, when clicking an Item, I see in the ClickEvent my lbCustomer is the correct Item, but the SelectedValue is wrong. In fact lbCustomer.SelectedValue returns the id as if there was no sorting, so if I select the first item in my ListBox, it returns the actual first (not sorted) customer.id from my DataSource-BindingList. Is this the usual outcome? I thought using DisplayMember and ValueMember is to prevent this behavior. How might i prevent this (without the need to sort my BindingList in the begining)?

Here is my code for connecting my list- and combo-Boxes with the DataSource:

```
private void SelectCorrectBox(bool dependence)
{
    DeactivateEvents();
    ChangeItems(lbCustomer, null, Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource, false);

    if(!dependence)
        ChangeItems(null, cbCustomer, Entity.DataSource.LbCustomer.CustomerSource, false);
    ChangeItems(lbProdukt, null, Entity.DataSource.LbProdukt.ProduktSource, false);
    ChangeItems(null, cbProdukt, Entity.DataSource.LbProdukt.ProduktSource, false);

    //if(dependence)
        ChangeItems(lbVersion, null, Entity.DataSource.LbVersion.VersionSource, false);

    ChangeItems(lbKategorie, null, Entity.DataSource.LbKategorie.KategorieSource, false);
    ChangeItems(lbFehler, null, Entity.DataSource.LbFehler.FehlerSource, true);
    ActivateEvents();
}

private void ChangeItems(ListBox lb, ComboBox cb, object source, bool fehler)
{
    if (cb == null)
    {
        lb.DataSource = source;

        if (!fehler)
            lb.DisplayMember = "name";
        else
            lb.DisplayMember = "titel";

        lb.ValueMember = "id";
        lb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
    else if (cb != null)
    {
        cb.DataSource = source;
        cb.DisplayMember = "name";
        cb.ValueMember = "id";
        cb.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

---

Edit:

The solution was using SelectedItem instead of SelectedValue:

Before:

```
private void lbCustomer_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EventStarter(lbCustomer.SelectedValue, "customer");
}
```

After:

```
private void lbCustomer_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EventStarter(((Entity.Customer)lbCustomer.SelectedItem).id, "customer");
}
```